# Anchoring UI elements based on a JSON response

Tags: swift, uiview, autolayout

I need to create a view layer composed of components layed out as per an api response.

Imagine I have a JSON response something like -

```
{ 
   "id":"1fbcf51b-1811-405d-ba92-de5110910f83",
   "name":"Gaming day",
   "contentTemplate":{ 
      "id":"300c01c3-747e-4446-8193-c2d633bfa8da",
      "name":"Social Announcement",
      "defaultLayoutId":"article",
      "layouts":[ 
         { 
            "id":"article",
            "body":[ 
               { 
                  "classType":"CONTAINER",
                  "category":"CONTAINER",
                  "type":"FULL_WIDTH",
                  "elements":[ 
                     { 
                        "classType":"TEXT",
                        "category":"INPUT",
                        "type":"TITLE",
                        "fieldId":"title"
                     },
                     { 
                        "classType":"TEXT",
                        "category":"INPUT",
                        "type":"SUMMARY",
                        "fieldId":"subtitle"
                     },
                     { 
                        "classType":"IMAGE",
                        "category":"INPUT",
                        "type":"IMAGE",
                        "fieldId":"mainImage"
                     },
                     { 
                        "classType":"TEXT",
                        "category":"INPUT",
                        "type":"RICH_TEXT",
                        "fieldId":"body"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               { 
                  "classType":"CONTAINER",
                  "category":"CONTAINER",
                  "type":"TWO_COLUMN_GRID",
                  "elements":[ 
                     { 
                        "classType":"IMAGE",
                        "category":"INPUT",
                        "type":"IMAGE",
                        "fieldId":"image1"
                     },
                     { 
                        "classType":"TEXT",
                        "category":"INPUT",
                        "type":"RICH_TEXT",
                        "fieldId":"body1"
                     },
                     { 
                        "classType":"TEXT",
                        "category":"INPUT",
                        "type":"RICH_TEXT",
                        "fieldId":"body2"
                     },
                     { 
                        "classType":"IMAGE",
                        "category":"INPUT",
                        "type":"IMAGE",
                        "fieldId":"image2"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               { 
                  "classType":"CONTAINER",
                  "category":"CONTAINER",
                  "type":"FULL_WIDTH",
                  "elements":[ 
                     { 
                        "classType":"METADATA",
                        "category":"METADATA",
                        "type":"RELATED_ARTICLES"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here you can see `layouts` contains an array of elements, all of the same type, some with more, optional properties and some with nested elements also.

It essentially describes the component and the way it should be presented

1. a full width row, with 4 elements stacked
2. a 2 column grid with those element stacked across both columns
3. a full width row, containing a single element

This would look something like this -

[image]

This is one example, but other layouts will follow this JSON structure.

At a very high level, I am building each component as a subclass of `UIView` and allow it to accept a model of sorts, to set the data for each element displayed. They will all conform to a `LayoutComponent` protocol and have some standard values that are set. This is pretty straight forward at this point.

I will then use a factory to 'build' the component for the given type.

As everything will be a subclass of `UIView` I should be OK.

What I am unsure of at this point is how to handle the layout of the components in relation to each other. The internal layout of each component is straight forward as I can anchor elements where I need to know as I am aware of what elements exist within each component.

When it comes to anchoring the sum of these elements to the `UIView` of the presenting `UIViewController` because the layout is dynamic I am can't work out how to tell the last `FULL_WIDTH` element to anchor to the bottom, and the element before that to anchor to it's bottom to the top of it etc.

If feels like I am potentially ending up with a huge amount of `if` statements and auto layout code.

Comment: Have you considered using a `UIStackView` for each 'container' element? You could set the properties for how it should render based on some props in your data and then you would not need to worry about anchoring to the top level superview

Comment: Definitely agree with others a UIStackView is the way to go on this. This looks like a fun puzzle to solve, so I will tinker with it if I get time today and post a link to a repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIStackView does this for you as long as each sub element has an intrinsic content size or a constraint for the direction of the stack (width for horizontal stacks and height for vertical stacks).

The whole thing should be a vertical stackview and each row should be a horizontal stackview.  If you think it will be bigger than the screen then put it in a scrollview and anchor the vertical stack to the contentLayoutGuide with a width constraint equal to the scrollViews parent; it will then scroll vertically only of its too big to show.

Apple's stackview guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to use the UICollectionView for this task. 
This class implements the reuse of cells and this will not consume a lot of memory when displaying a list

You need a cell like ImageCell, TextCell and another elements. This cell should be drawing content for specified size (using sizeThatFits and layoutSubviews or autolayout)

For implementing few layout rules you have two possible ways:

1) Create custom UICollectionViewLayout, [doc from Apple](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwjPv7y34KPmAhUDlosKHRiUAG0QFjABegF%25TF%25TF%25TF%25TF%25TFF%202Fuicollectionview%25%202Fcustomizing_collection_view_layouts%20&%20usg%20=%20AOvVaw0slC77X6PKzC8oE54c8NrB)

2) Another ways is create layout cell like TwoColumnCell, FullWidthCell. And adding elements cell like subviews for layouting cell.

The second way breaks reusing cells, because you can't reuse cell for concrete element type. 
And you can implement this way based on UIView, not UICollectionView. Idea is having few cell's classes for layouting and few cell's classes for drawing contents